# Does Infinispan support native operations for structured values like Redis?

Tags: redis, infinispan

We're using Redis but considering Infinispan. Redis supports list, hashset, set, and sorted set, and offers native functions to operate over those structures, but does Infinispan support the same?

I know Infinispan will store any Java object, but Redis offers functions that operate on elements without having to explicitly retrieve them. I was wondering if Infinispan supports the same.

Comment: Infiniband??? You mean infinispan, right? http://infinispan.org/

Comment: @DidierSpezia yes, lol; sorry, long day :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infinispan does not support this out-of-the-box - there is some support for AtomicHashMaps, although I've heard that there may be issues with those.

The main feature you should be looking for is the [DeltaAware interface](http://blog.infinispan.org/2012/06/fine-grained-replication-in-infinispan.html) - this allows you to build such collections, sending just the 'operation' that should be executed on the value.

There were some attempts to do so - check out [infinispan-contrib](https://github.com/saturnism/infinispan-contrib) (though I don't have any experience with that).